# cant install osx 10.8 - error "the disk is used for time machine" - its my main HD

Tags: macos, mac, upgrade, osx-mountain-lion, time-machine

Im trying to upgrade to 10.8 from 10.7.5 on my "13-inch macbook, aluminum late 2008", when i run the install i click agree on the T&C, and then i get to select the HD i want to install it on (but i cant select it, as it says its used for time machine backups, but as far as i can tell its not), i only have 1 HD, no externals, and that HD is used by the machine.

Is there a way it could have been backing up to itself ? and if so how can i turn it off ?

I also use an external HD for time machine backups, but when im doing this install its not connected.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging around i found the answer, you need to go into the root of your HD and move a folder called backups.backupdb into the trash (but dont delete it by emptying the trash) then run the install as normal it wont through this error this time.

Once you've run the install, take the backups.backupdb folder and place it back in to the root of your HD.